# django views - 502 bad gateway

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm testing my project in the production server where I'm getting several errors of various features in my web application which is working perfectly on my computer.

Please go to http://qlimp.com and login using this **username/password: nirmal/karurkarur** Then go to http://qlimp.com/cover You'll find a palette where you can upload images and do something similar to **flavors.me**. I'm having several problems here(images,text,other information are not getting stored in the database).

I think there is no problem with the setup. The problem is it is not even entering into the Django views properly but working without any problem on my computer. Is there anyone experienced the same problem? I'm wondering why is it not working.

Also you can check out in http://qlimp.com/signup/ and you can find the problem where the datas are not get stored.

So there are many problems which I can't ask in one question(not a stackoverflow culture) and so I'm asking this.

When I upload the image I checked in **chrome inspector 'network tab'** it shows **502 bad gateway**

Here is my Django **views.py**: https://gist.github.com/2778242

**jQuery** Code for the **ajax image upload**:

```
$('#id_tmpbg').live('change', function()
    {
    $("#ajax-loader").show();
    $("#uploadform").ajaxForm({success: showResponse}).submit();
    });

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
    $.backstretch(responseText)
    $("#ajax-loader").hide();
    }
```

And I also checked that it is actually entering into the `request.is_ajax()` but not into `form.is_valid()` in my views. Why is it so? I'm uploading the right format.

Could anyone identify the mistake I've done? Also I need an answer on Why the code is not working on production server which is actually working on the development server (this would be helpful for me to solve rest of the problems).

Development server: Ubuntu 11.10/Python 2.7/Django 1.3.1

Production server: Ubuntu 12.04/Python 2.7/Django 1.3.1

**UPDATE**

There is some problem in everyone signing in with the same user/password. So please register there and it shows **[Errno 111] Connection refused**, doesn't matter, you can login then.

**UPDATE-2**

Actually the problem is with form.is_valid() so I removed it and checked but now I'm getting this error:

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    The BackgroundModel could not be created because the data didn't validate.
Exception Location: /home/nirmal/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in save_instance, line 73
```

I'm all-time uploading the right Image format and I don't know why it is not validating.

**UPDATE-3**

I'm getting **304 Not Modified** for all the static files in http://qlimp.com/cover Will this be a problem for not working?

Comment: Login doesn't seem to work. I just keep getting cycled back to the login form.

Comment: oh sorry @PeterRowell check it now

Comment: Fix the indentation in your gist, because as its written it is not valid Python.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I don't see any indentation mistake there. where is it?

Comment: Nevermind, was looking at the wrong gist, but you don't have a condition for when the form is not valid.

Comment: Ok @BurhanKhalid I will do it later. But I'm actually uploading the right file format and why is not getting validated

Comment: You can't know why because you are assuming that all forms will be valid. So, add an `else` to check for when the form is not valid and print an appropriate message.

Comment: 502 means your application has gone away and webserver couldn't find it. How are you running your app? Is there something in the logs?

Comment: @ilvar through `gunicorn_django -bind=127.0.0.1:8001`. I'll check the logs and tell you.

Comment: @ilvar There is nothing in the nginx and gunicorn error log. My question is how can I get problem in the django views which is working in my computer?. I can't find the cause of the problem.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid As I told in the question. The problem is it is not entering into the form.is_valid() block, But I uploaded the right image file format. Why?

Comment: It seems to be an issue related to production environment. So check what changes there: Django version, Python, HTTP server, etc.

Comment: @grosshat Django and python versions are the one that 've shown in the question section. But HTTP server? how can I check it?

Comment: I updated the question. Please check it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have full permission to read/write in `MEDIA_ROOT` directory of production server?

Comment: @borges Yes, I'm the administrator on the production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem which was stucking me for the past 3 days. It is because I've forget to  do this `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev` before the PIL installation, that is why the image is not get validated.

The next issue is I've given a relative path for the MEDIA_ROOT in my settings.py file which leads to `404 NOT FOUND` and I changed it to absolute path.

So these are simple mistakes which leads to some mysterious errors. Also Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's Nginx that gives the 502 error when gunicorn is not available.

`gunicorn_django -bind=127.0.0.1:8001` only launches one synchronous worker process and it may be busy responding to other requests.

You may want to spawn more workers (`-w2`). If you need to handle big data transfers consider using an asynchronous worker flavor (e.g. `-k gevent`, you need gevent to be installed).

More info on choosing the worker class and the number of workers in [Gunicorn FAQ](http://gunicorn.org/faq.html).